# Get user input from HTML and search JSON array for value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

Let´s say I have a Json File which looks like this:

```
{"403": [ { "403-01-01": "219,00" }, { "403-01-02": "180,00" } ], 
 "404": [ { "404-01-01": "26,00" }, {"403-01-02": "2612,00"} ] }
```

> *the file is much bigger and probably when finished has like 400+ Entries*

and i want a user to input something on a website  like `403-01-02` how would i be able to get the input into a js value and search the array for the value of the entry and display it to the user.

> maybe having each new set of starting codes (`403`, `404`...etc) as a new array is a dumb idea and it does not have to be that way but i think it looks better when viewed so i chose to format it like this first

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the desired result? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible also include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It seems like you are asking for multiple things at once. We should break it down first: Having your user input something and storing the value is part a). You can achieve that with a html input element and using javascript to read from that input. Finding a solution to searching an array for a certain key/value is part b).

Comment: There is a package, https://github.com/joewalnes/filtrex its meant to sanitize input and stuff. I think you would need to load the data into memory or write a json adapter for yourself though. Another option is to use lowdb https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?
This code log the value of the entry given to `userRequest`

```
let array = {
    "403": [ { "403-01-01": "219,00" }, { "403-01-02": "180,00" } ],
    "404": [ { "404-01-01": "26,00" }, {"403-01-02": "2612,00"} ]
};
let userRequest = "403-01-02";
let arrayEntry = userRequest.split('-')[0];
let requestValue = array[arrayEntry].filter(function(el) {
        return userRequest in el;
});
console.log(requestValue[0][userRequest]);
```